# Почему класс вне видимости файла?

Tags: c++, классы

Есть три файла: Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Triangle test;

    return 0;
}
```

Заголовочный class.h

```
#pragma once
#include "class.cpp"

class Triangle
{
    double a, b, gamma;
public:
    void SetSideA(double);
    void SetSideB(double);
    void SetAngleBetween(double);
    void GetData();

};
```

И файл с определениями class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

void Triangle::SetSideA(double x)
{
    a = x;
}
void Triangle::SetSideB(double x)
{
    b = x;
}
void Triangle::SetAngleBetween(double x)
{
    gamma = x;
}
void Triangle::GetData()
{
    std::cout << "CLASS TRIANGLE: \n side A = " << a << "\nside B = " << b << "\nAngle between = " << gamma << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

В командной при вызове g++ ./main.cpp выводится ошибка

> Triangle' was not declared in this scope

В чем проблема? Вроде бы все файлы подключены

Comment: На всякий случай добавьте в вопрос всё-таки **полный** стек-трейс ошибки. Может он и не даст никакой информации, но мало ли.

Comment: `#include "class.cpp"` - что это, зачем это

Comment: Как что? Файлик где определения функций пишутся, не очень понял

Comment: Для начала, это не файлик, а директива препроцессора.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно заменить строку `#include "class.cpp"` из `class.h` на `#include <iostream>` и вызывать `g++ ./main.cpp ./class.cpp`. Все новые `cpp` файлы нужно будет дописывать в вызов аналогичным образом. Есть ленивый вариант: `g++ *.cpp`.

В вашем варианте ответа вы просто склеиваете все файлы в один с помощью директив препроцессора.

Comment: Спасибо, стало яснее, только ленивый вариант почему-то не работает cc1plus.exe: fatal error: *.cpp: Invalid argument
compilation terminated.